# how to implement service manager in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I followed the documentation on AWS how to add [system manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-instance-profile.html).

So i did **EC2-> Instances** and select my running **EKS instance** to **add** the **policies** to the existing **IAM Role** `eksctl-eks-gxxxxx-nodegroup-NodeInstanceRole-S0UHXXXXHJJD3T` .

As you can see on the screenshot we can see `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` on the **IAM Role**
[eksctl-eks-gxxxxx-nodegroup-NodeInstanceRole-S0UHXXXXHJJD3T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYvX4.png) .

However when i go to **system Manager -> Session manager**  i dont see my instance :(
i get this error

> There are no instances which are associated with the required IAM
> role.

i also watched a movie on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2P3ajglqbKw) I do everything the same I don't see where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed SSM Agent on the EC2 instance?

You need the SSM Agent running on the system to perform any actions by SSM. More details on how to install and configure the agent could be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html

Comment: i used Amazon Linux 2 from aws

Comment: That should have SSM Agent pre-installed. Just verify if it is running. Also verify the IAM Instance Profile attached with the system have relevant permissions. 
What I do in these scenarios is provide "ALL" permissions to IAM Role to verify if that's the actual issue or something else..

Comment: how can i verify if SSM Agent is running on my instance ?

Comment: These 2 links should help you: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent-get-version.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent-status-and-restart.html

Comment: i followed the step  **System manager -> Quick setup**  when i go  to check the details i have  **AWS-QuickSetup-SSMHostMgmt-CollectInventory-mzf9b Pending**   due to that i can have my instance in **System manger -> Fleet Manager ** to check the version of **SSM**

Comment: on this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-manual-agent-install.html) they said this ->  For example, SSM Agent is not preinstalled on EKS-Optimized AMIs based on Amazon Linux 2. :( :(

Comment: But on [that one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/agent-install-al2.html) they said this  -> SSM Agent is installed, by default, on Amazon Linux base AMIs dated 2017.09 and later. SSM Agent is also installed, by default, on Amazon Linux 2 AMIs. You must manually install SSM Agent on other versions of Linux.